# Does TSIG and DNSSEC provide encryption of entire DNS packet?

Tags: security, dnssec, dns-server

it says TSIG and DNSSEC provide authentication. Does it mean whole DNS traffic would be encrypted so if I do packet capturing I would not be able to parse anything ?

Or DNS data is still plain text but it has a signature on it so I would be able to verify the data if it is authentic ?

I tried to search TSIG packet data diagram but no luck. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both TSIG and DNSSEC provide authentication only.

The data is still unencrypted but signatures are added to allow verification.